# Using Handlebars data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I feel like I'm trying to do something simple but I'm not phrasing it right to find the answers I need.

I'm working on a BigCommerce site. I need to change the way the quantity is displayed, but only for certain brands. I know the Handlebar expression for the brand of the product is {{brands}}

How can I use that in my jQuery to say "If the brand is 'Apple' then add this class to the quantity box" ?

If I put "console.log ({{brands}});" in the code, I get this:

[image]

The input field I'm trying to target with jQuery is

```
<input class="form-input form-input--incrementTotal" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" type="tel" value="1" data-quantity-min="0" data-quantity-max="0" min="1" pattern="[0-9]*" aria-live="polite">
```

Comment: we're gonna need some js and html to work with, what does {{brands}} output in the console, on what element do you intend to query with jQuery, something

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría I made some edits above

Comment: try it like this and see what outputs: `console.log('{{brands}}');`, notice the single quotes. I'm not entirely sure cause I think you r working with chrome and I have not, the way you are passing {{brands}} to console.log() is not working too well

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría if I set the console.log up the way you suggested I get back "{{brands}}" - minus the quotation marks. It doesn't seem to be accessing the actual value of the product brand.

Comment: well, do you have any way of knowing what `{{brands}}` contains, what structure/format it has?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, assuming `{{brands}}` contains a string (i.e. just one brand, like 'Apple')

```
var brand = "{{brands}}"; //use double quotes
if(brand === 'Apple')
    $('input.form-input').addClass('someClass');
```

LMK